# Cannot Post A Value In An Input Placeholder

Tags: php, html, post, input, placeholder

I have a form and I want to make an update.In the update page I also want to show the

current values to the user. There is no problem with getting the values from database and
putting them into placeholders. But when i click my button all the values in placeholders are
turning into NULL. I want support on this problem. Thanks anyway.

View:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>Personel/personel_duzenle_kaydet/<?=$pr_edit_data[0]->Id?>"">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">T.C. Kimlik No</label>
        <input  name="tc_kimlik" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?=$pr_edit_data[0]->tc_kimlik?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Personel Ünvanı</label>
        <select name="unvan" class="form-control" >
            <option><?=$pr_edit_data[0]->unvan?></option>
            <option>Pazarlama</option>
            <option>Şef</option>
            <option>Marangoz</option>
            <option>Dekor Elemanı</option>
            <option>Teknik Ekip</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">İşe Başlama Tarihi</label>
        <input name="is_tarihi" type="text" placeholder="<?=$pr_edit_data[0]->is_tarihi?>" data-mask="99-99-9999" class="form-control">
    </div>
        <button style="float: right" type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> PERSONELİ KAYDET </button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 public function personel_duzenle_kaydet ($id)
    {
        $data = array (
            'tc_kimlik' => $this -> input -> post ('tc_kimlik'),
        'ad_soyad' => $this -> input -> post ('ad_soyad'),
        'adres' => $this -> input -> post ('adres'),
        'maas' => $this -> input -> post ('maas'),  
        'hesap_no' => $this -> input -> post ('hesap_no'),
        'unvan' => $this -> input -> post ('unvan'),    
        'sigorta_durumu' => $this -> input -> post ('sigorta_durumu'),
        'sigorta_baslangic_tarihi' => $this -> input -> post ('sigorta_baslangic_tarihi'),
        'is_tarihi' => $this -> input -> post ('is_tarihi'),
            );
        $this ->General_Database_Model->update_data("personel",$data,$id);
        redirect(base_url()."Personel/");
    }
</code>
Model:
<code>
public function update_data ($table,$data,$id)
{
    $this->db->where("Id",$id);
    $this->db->update($table,$data);
}
</code>
```

Comment: What php framework are you using?